# How to add bouncy castle algorithm to Androidproject

Tags: android, encryption

Hiya!
I want to do AES/ECB/PKCS7 encryption in my android project. For that, I was thinking of using the bouncy castle algorithm. Can anybody tell me how to add this to the project? When I give the comand

Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());

it shows an error like "org.bouncycastle cannot be resolved to a type".

Comment: Check the following link too                                       http://code.google.com/p/bcandroid/source/checkout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that did not included Bouncy Castle library into the project. If you are using Eclipse, see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/commontasks.html#addexternallibrary) how to do it.